# How to call NumberPicker's onvaluechange from SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-number-picker

I want to update the NumberPicker using the value stored in Shared Preferences. This is all happening inside a fragment, there is also a button which calls the `onValueChange()` method whenever the user clicks on it.

HomeFragment.java

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

NumberPicker numberPicker;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    numberPicker = (NumberPicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.np);

    //Populate NumberPicker values from minimum and maximum value range
    //Set the minimum value of NumberPicker
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    //Specify the maximum value/number of NumberPicker
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(239);

    //Gets whether the selector wheel wraps when reaching the min/max value.
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

    //Set a value change listener for NumberPicker
    final NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener np_listener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){

            //Statement goes here...

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("someInteger", newVal);
            editor.commit();
        }
    };

    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(np_listener);

    b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int oldValue = numberPicker.getValue();
            numberPicker.setValue(oldValue + 1);
            np_listener.onValueChange(numberPicker, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
        }
    });


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Whenever the NumberPicker value changes, I'm saving it in Preferences but where to retrieve the value? I know the code to retrieve:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int someInteger = sharedPref.getInt("someInteger", 0);
```

But where to put this code, inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`? After the value is retrieved if it exists then how to call `onValueChange()` so that all the statements inside that method gets executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call it from `SharedPreferences`.

Inside `onCreateView`, set the `NumberPicker` value using the `setValue` method.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... some code ...

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Use default value 0 if key does not exist
    int someInteger = sharedPref.getInt("someInteger", 0);

    numberPicker = (NumberPicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.np);
    numberPicker.setValue(someInteger);

    // ...

}
```

Comment: And to call `onValueChange()`, I'm using `np_listener.onValueChange(numberPicker, someInteger - 1, someInteger);` just after the listener is added to number picker.